# Issue with PL/SQL Query of how to use exists and not exists

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle10g, plsqldeveloper

I have a table with location details:-

```
Location id    Manager Name             SubFunction      
  1             HR      XYZ             direct sales    
  2             IT      ABC             Gaming         
   3            HR      DEC              Agent     

Location id   Lookupcode
1          123
2          126
3          231
4          222
```

Subfuction_table detail :-

```
Lookup code  Subfunction
123          Agent
126          Gaming
222          Customer services
```

Basically, I have two tables one with the locations having function , sub function defined 
and another one with subfunction table having subfunction names which is used in the location table.

Now i have to write a PL/SQL query such that all those functions which do not exist in the location table gets displayed having manager as 'HR' only. I have tried the below query :-

```
select Subfuntion
from subfunction_table
where exists                     //Part a
(select null
from subfunction_table

)
and not exists
(select null                 // Partb
from 
location
where manger='HR')
```

For example :- in the above table in the subfunction table there is 'Customer service' which is in the subfuncn table but not in the location so the query should display the subfunction ' Customer services'

But i am not getting the logic as to how to use the subfunction name from Part a to Part b

Comment: so, you are using SQL Server but the language is PLSQL instead of T-SQL?

Comment: wrong tag.. i corrected it.. i m using sql developer

Comment: Where do the functions "not in the locations" table come from?

Comment: functions ans sub sub function table are seperately defined just as subfunctions.. but it isnt required so i didnt mention

Comment: Are Location and Subfunction_table joined on numerical key `location.SubFunction=Subfunction_table.Lookup`?

Comment: a thrd table is being used. have reedited... i just want the exist and not exist logic. rest ill do

Comment: If you try a query with an OUTER JOIN to the subfunction_table, then you'll have NULLs returned on the Location side of the join - which can be filtered easily. Not sure what you mean by "gets displayed having manager as 'HR' only"

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
  FROM subfunction sf
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                     FROM function f JOIN location l USING (locationid)
                    WHERE l.manager = 'HR');
```

I this what you're looking for? This is what I understood from your question.